# Number of subsets in set with sum equal to 10

Tags: elementary-set-theory, word-problem

Consider a set containing the integers between 1 and 10 (inclusive). How many unique subsets exist such that the sum of the elements of the subset is 10?

I know this is easily done by hand, but I was wondering if there is a general formula that exists to solve such a problem.

**Edit**: I was given the answer below, but, writing out the sets, I appear to get the answer to be 9. The unique sets I get are {7,1,2}, {6,1,3}, {5,1,4}, {5,2,3}, {9,1}, {8,2}, {7,3}, {6,4}, {1,2,3,4}. Also, could someone please explain how ones gets that q(10) = 10 in the Answer?

Thank You

Comment: For sum equal to $10$, or $n$, look for information under *partitions into distinct parts*. Big literature, dating back to Euler. No nice closed form formula, but pleasant enough generating function, and recurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalent question is the number of [integer partitions of 10 into distinct parts](http://functions.wolfram.com/IntegerFunctions/PartitionsQ/introductions/Partitions/ShowAll.html).  This is sometimes denoted as $q(n)$.  Quite a bit is known about this function, e.g. $q(10)=10$, but there is no nice closed-form formula.

Comment: Thank you for the link. However, just writing it out, I appear to get the answer to be 9. The unique sets I get are {7,1,2}, {6,1,3}, {5,1,4}, {5,2,3}, {9,1}, {8,2}, {7,3}, {6,4}, {1,2,3,4}. Further, could you please explain how you got that q(10) = 10?

Comment: You missed {10}.